# Setting up a new cloudprovider for Kubernetes

Tags: git, kubernetes, apache-cloudstack

I'm trying to develop horizontal scaling for kubernetes deployed on a vm in CloudStack. On the github repo I understood that a [fake provider](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/fake) used to develop new cloudprovider, that I want to do. The problem is that I'm a nood in using git and Kubernetes. So my questions are:

- if I edit fake.go in such a way, than how do I say to Kubernetes that I want that cloudprovider?
- I know that there is kubernetes  for CoreOS, but I have to use it in CentOS, because when I'm done these changes I have to use with OpenShit, but this is another story...

Could someone help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The fake provider is just for testing, not for developing a new cloud provider, but it does show you which methods need to be implemented. It's worth looking at one of the real provider implementations, though.

You can find the platforms and distros to which Kubernetes has been ported here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/getting-started-guides

A baremetal (no cloud provider) CentOS setup can be found here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config.md

A Cloudstack setup is described here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/cloudstack.md